# Auto arrange tabs to fit with max text length in python printing

Tags: python

How do I arrange the tab to suit the max text length so that it doesn't overflow?  How can I give an additional tab for the first column?

```
print ('----------------------------')
print ('customer', 'order', 'qty', 'category', sep=('\t'))

for p in orders_placed:
        # Do something
        print(customer_name , int(order),  int(qty), category ,sep=('\t'))


----------------------------
planet  order   qty     category
cust1   7       6       grocery
cust2   10      9       grocery
cust1234       11      10      grocery #trying to fix this overflow
```

Comment: For these cases I use a pad function which takes in a string and pads it with spaces to a certain length. Then I calculate the length of the longest customer name and pad every name to that amount of spaces.

Comment: Maybe this answer can help you: [how to print dynamic 2D list in an aligned manner in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58998611/12400173)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do this by applying string formatting in python.

```
print ('----------------------------')
print ('customer', 'order', 'qty', 'category', sep=('\t'))

for p in orders_placed:
        # Do something
        print ('{:<10s}{:<8d}{:<4d}{:>3s}'.format(customer_name, int(order) ,int(qty), category))


#'{:<10s}{:<8d}{:<4d}{:>3s}.format(any string) # format to meet the string ahead the job.



------------------------------------
customer  order   qty category
cust1        7     6 grocery  
cust2       10     9 grocery  
cust1234    11    10 grocery
```

Answer (score 1):

strings have a function ljust which adds spaces to increase the size to the given value:

```
def print_table(array):
    max_widths = []
    for column in zip(*array):
        max_widths.append(max(map(len, map(str, column))))
    for row in array:
        for width, cell in zip(max_widths, row):
            print(str(cell).ljust(width+1), end="")
        print()
```

Explaination: the first for-loop calculates the width needed for every column by calling `str()` and `len()` on every cell.

The second for-loop calls `str()` and `ljust()` on every cell and prints it. `width+1` is to ensure that there is at least one space everywhere between the columns.

Test Code:

```
a = [
    ["Hello", "World", "foo", "bar"],
    [1, 2**20, 9, "Python is cool"],
    ["abc", "def", "ghi", "jkl"],
]

print_table(a)
```

Comment: Tried to apply your algorithm to dir(str) in hopes it would give my a perfect tabbed list of strings but it did not work. =(

Answer (score 0):

You can't, tab stops are a function of the display system.

What you *can* do is check the maximum size of your columns, store this information, and then pad columns to the relevant size when printing.

That does require two passes on the data but works fine. There are probably packages which can do that for you on pypi if you don't want to hand-roll it.

Alternatively, depending on your needs, you could just print space-separated data and feed it to `column(1)`:

```
❯ echo "planet    order  qty  category
cust1     7      6    grocery
cust2     10     9    grocery
cust1234  11     10   grocery
" | column -t
planet    order  qty  category
cust1     7      6    grocery
cust2     10     9    grocery
cust1234  11     10   grocery
```

(though that means you can't e.g. right-align your numbers, which you *could* do in python)